# Flutter location picker crashes on real device on release apk

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, dart, location

I've used [Google map location picker](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_location_picker/install) package to let the user pick a location in my flutter application, and here is what I did :

***Android Manifest***

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"  />


    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Delivery runner - vendor"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="///My Api written here///" />
```

Then in my dart file:

```dart
await showLocationPicker(
context,
'<My API >',
myLocationButtonEnabled:true,).then(() => what ever i want to do );
```

While running a debug APK or emulator, it works perfectly .. once I start using my release APK.. it crashes right after I execute `showLocationPicker`.. it opens the Location permission granting dialog, and in few milliseconds before I take any action. the application is crashed.

**NOTE**

I have tried to use [Permission Handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) to ask for permission when the app starts way before going to the map screen, and it grants permission successfully, but still crashes when I try to open the location picker screen.

**UPDATE**

- i have tried to remove :

```dart
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"  />
```

but the same result.

- The project already migrated to android X.

Comment: What is the version of android on your real device? API level?

Comment: Android Version 10 API level 29

Comment: As its on real device, hope you have added INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml in android>app>src>main?

Comment: Yes I did, the application have many other requests over the internet that works well before reaching the map

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: there is flutter issue already opened [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105965)